# What kind of thing is a fooBar.category file in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, categories

I recently opened the package of an iPhone app because I was curious how all that stuff looks like when the app is built. There, I found something like fooBar.category. What's that? I don't think it's a "Category" in terms of Cocoa, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something specific to the app you were looking at :) Have you tried opening the file to see the contents?